# PHP real_usage lower than internal usage, why?

Tags: php, memory

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290611/tracking-memory-usage-in-php) question

> real_usage works this way:
>
> Zend's memory manager does not use system malloc for every block it
>   needs. Instead, it allocates a big block of system memory (in
>   increments of 256K, can be changed by setting environment variable
>   ZEND_MM_SEG_SIZE) and manages it internally. So, there are two kinds
>   of memory usage:
>
> 1. How much memory the engine took from the OS ("real usage")
> 2. How much of
>      this memory was actually used by the application ("internal usage")

The same thing can be found on the official PHP [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php):

> real_usage
>
> Set this to TRUE to get total memory allocated from system,
>   including unused pages. If not set or FALSE only the used memory is
>   reported.

So I tested and I found that

```
var_dump(memory_get_usage()); //--> 4391096
var_dump(memory_get_usage(true)); //--> 2097152
```

So the real_usage seems 2Mb that is lower than internal usage (4Mb), how can this be possible? I understood that real_usage should be grater than internal usage. (I'm on windows, php7)

Thanks